# I am not able to run vim or nano command to change the content of a file inside POD file system also bash-4.2 is prompted

Tags: kubernetes, vim, nano

I am trying to `exec` into POD running over K8S using below command,

```
kubectl exec -it entry-log -n my-ns  -- /bin/bash
```

I am able to inside POD file system and wanted to edit the file `log.conf` using either `nano` or `vim` commands, but nothing is available here? Also I am seeing it's prompt as `bash-4.2`.

```
bash-4.2$ cd code/
bash-4.2$ nano log.conf
bash: nano: command not found
```

How can I edit the said file, please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your Dockerfile for the container ?

Comment: You are not supposed to edit that file in a container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the image of your container?

If your image is `ubuntu:focal` or `ubuntu:jammy`, they don't have the commands like `nano` or `vim` by default. You should install these either to your Dockerfile for your image or to your container using:

```bash
apt-get update && apt-get install nano -y
```